# scheme input port eof

Tags: scheme, mit-scheme

it's all about scheme and its input system, let's get started, I got this input, and the program have to keep reading till eof.

```
]=> (getallinput)
22 (5(4(11(7()())(2()()))()) (8(13()())(4()(1()()))))
20 (5(4(11(7()())(2()()))()) (8(13()())(4()(1()()))))
```

And this is the function

```
(define (getAllinput)
  (let ((port console-i/o-port))
    (letrec ((nread (lambda (port)
                      (let ((value (read port)))
                        (let ((tree (read port)))
                          (display (findValor (sum tree) value))
                          (if (not (eof-object? port))
                              (nread port)))))))
      (nread port))))
```

The thing is, I'm having problems with ending up reading from console, and the letrec, I know where the problem is, I don't know how to solve it though.

```
(if (not (eof-object? tree)) (nread port)))))))(nread port))))
```

It stick reading the input back and forth, thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

In the function shown in the question, you are checking `(eof-object? port)` which will never become true, while you should check `(eof-object? tree)` as shown further down in your question, or `(eof-object? value)`

Also, you should check this condition before using the read values in the `findValor` function:

```
(define (getAllinput)
  (let ((port console-i/o-port))
    (letrec ((nread (lambda (port)
                      (let* ((value (read port))
                             (tree (read port)))
                        (if (not (eof-object? value))   ; <--
                            (begin
                              (display (findValor (sum tree) value))
                              (nread port)))))))
      (nread port))))
```

Answer (score 0):

In order for `eof-object?` to return true, you must actually send an end-of-file if you're reading from the console. In Unix, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd>; in Windows, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Comment: I knew that, but the thing I need it to do is, once pressed intro, the input must end, and must return the result, I tried (eq? read  #\newline) instead of (not (eof-object? port)), but It's still not working

Comment: If you use `read`, the only way to get `#\newline` is if you actually enter `#\newline` literally in the input. :-) But if you use `read-char`, it will work as you expect---but, you should use `peek-char`, so that if it's not newline, you can read the next expression without eating the first char! Also, don't use `eq?` for character comparisons: use `eqv?`. Thus, all in all: `(eqv? (peek-char) #\newline)`.